# Props in Tab.Navigation react navigation not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I make a Navigation component and put all screen in it.
it working well, but props in Tab.Navigation not work such as barStyle,initialRouteName,....
I make stack for each screen and put all stack in bottom navigation and i wanna change option for bottom navigation but I cant.
I set initialRouteName and bar style but now working at all.
Thanks for response.

```js
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import CollectionScreen from '../screens/Collection';
import LiveScreen from '../screens/Live';
import PrayScreen from '../screens/Pray';
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/Profile';
import PublicationScreen from '../screens/Publication';
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const LiveStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function LiveStackScreen() {
  return (
    <LiveStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <LiveStack.Screen name="LiveScreen" component={LiveScreen} />
    </LiveStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const ProfileStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function ProfileStackScreen() {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const PrayStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function PrayStackScreen() {
  return (
    <PrayStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <PrayStack.Screen name="PrayScreen" component={PrayScreen} />
    </PrayStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const PublicationStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function PublicationStackScreen() {
  return (
    <PublicationStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <PublicationStack.Screen
        name="PublicationScreen"
        component={PublicationScreen}
      />
    </PublicationStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const CollectionStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function CollectionStackScreen() {
  return (
    <CollectionStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <CollectionStack.Screen
        name="CollectionScreen"
        component={CollectionScreen}
      />
    </CollectionStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        // This props not working
        initialRouteName="Profile"
        barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#694fad'}}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Live" component={LiveStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Pray" component={PrayStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Publication" component={PublicationStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Collection" component={CollectionStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some code snippets or more details?

Comment: @poPaTheGuru  i put snippets

Comment: i just tried that `initialRouteName` and it's working as expected, but `barStyle` is not a prop, you might want to try `tabStyle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why this snippets not working.
I wrote the code like below

```
initialRouteName="Profile"
```

But we must set initialRouteName like below

```
 initialRouteName={'Profile'}
```

and for changing background color of bottomTab you should do like below

```
 screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: 'red'},
    }}
```

Comment: tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: 'red'}, is only applied to 2 out of my 4 tabs. Why is that??